# Make composable wrap content - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make the `ImageComposable` wrap its height and width according to its content, along with the two `Text` composable, align to the bottom of `Assemble` composable. Following is the code for that:

```
@Composable
fun ImageComposable(url:String){
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(url).apply{
            placeholder(drawableResId = R.drawable.ic_broken_pic)
        }.build()
    )
    Image(painter = painter, contentDescription = null, Modifier.padding(2.dp).border(width = 2.dp, shape = CircleShape, color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)

}

@Composable
fun Assemble(url:String){
    Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(400.dp).background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        .padding(16.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom) {
        ImageComposable(url)
        Text(text = "title")
        Text(text = "Body")
    }
}
```

but the `ImageComposable` ends up taking all the height and width of the `Assemble` composable and I am not able to see the two `Text` composables that I added in the `column`. So I am confused as to what is the exact problem here. I thought at least it should show the `ImageComposable` along with the two `Text` composable but it is not happening.

I am using `coil` image loading library here for parsing the image from url. For now in testing, I am passing url as an `Empty String`. Hence I am calling the composable as:
`Assemble("")`

I didn't find any document that would help me understand this behavior. So I wanted to know the reason to this problem and possible solutions to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to solve your problem if there would be a sketch of what you want to achieve.

Nevertheless, I hope I can help:
It looks like the issue you are facing can be handled by [Intrinsic measurements in Compose layouts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements).

The column measures each child individually without the dimension of your text constraining the image size. For this `Intrinsics` can be used.

> Intrinsics lets you query children before they're actually measured.

> For example, if you ask the minIntrinsicHeight of a Text with infinite width, it'll return the height of the Text as if the text was drawn in a single line.

By using `IntrinsicSize.Max` for the `width` of the `Assemble` composable  like this:

```
@Composable
fun Assemble(url: String) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
            .padding(16.dp), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        ImageComposable(url)
        Text(text = "title")
        Text(text = "Body")
    }
}
```

you can can create a layout like this:

[image: Preview Assemble Composable]

(Please note that I am using a local drawable here)

You can now see the 2 texts and the width of the image is adjusted to the width of the texts.

Using `Intrinsics` to measure children in dependance to each other should help you to achieve what you wanted.

Please let me know if this layout does not meet your expectations.

Comment: this solution doesn't work when the image is loaded asynchronously

Answer (score -1):

You can explicitly specify the height of each component:

```
fun ImageComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, url: String){
//...
    Image(modifier = modifier, //...
}

Column(//..
   ImageComposable(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)//...
   Text(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp)//...
   Text(modifier = Modifier.height(150.dp)//...
}
```

Or you can specify a fraction of the maximum height it will take up:

```
fun ImageComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, url: String){
//...
    Image(modifier = modifier, //...
}

Column(//..
   ImageComposable(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.75f)//...
   Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.1f)//...
   Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.15f)//...
}
```

You can also try playing with the weight modifier:

```
fun ImageComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, url: String){
//...
    Image(modifier = modifier, //...
}

Column(//..
   ImageComposable(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)//...
   Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)//...
   Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)//...
}
```

Comment: This answer is totally wrong. He is asking how to wrap the component and you are giving workaround solutions by giving fixed sizes